# update number field value in nested angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, components

I have a nested/sub formgroup. It has a number field that need to update by clicking a button. I can update the value itself but I can't get the field updated.

How do I fix it?

here is the plnkr
https://plnkr.co/edit/ZN3cGHHRNvx7348x1PSm?p=preview

```
increment() {
  this.number++;
  this.adressForm.value.age = this.number++;

}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I looked at your plunkr and I still don't understand the question.  Your plunkr had no button and the form value does update the number when typed in.  You need to clarify your question more.

Comment: it wasn't `<button>` had `<span>` below the field. `<button>` re loading plunkr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `AddressComponent` change your code to

```
increment() {
  let currentAgeValue : number = this.adressForm.controls.age.value;
  this.adressForm.controls.age.setValue(currentAgeValue + 1);
}
```

Working forked [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WHkiZN2EVTPlq3bOotpg?p=preview)